# Tuple object not callable error in plt.bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe containing Facebook engagement data as well as attendance and "theme" information regarding a series of events.  The dataframe is called df:

```
FBDataSet = [["Saturday, June 16, 2012", "Desert Oasis", 25417, DesertOasis_postIDs, 121, 23, "Spring"], 
         ["Saturday, November 17, 2012", "The Golden Era", 15926, GoldenEra_postIDs, 797, 76, "Fall"], 
         ["Saturday, June 15, 2013", "The White Party 2013", 23509, WhiteParty13_postIDs, 667, 121, "Spring"], 
         ["Saturday, June 22, 2013", "Boots, Brew & BBQ 2013", 20034, BBQ13_postIDs, 1136, 195, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, September 7, 2013", "College Rivalry Night 2013", 13900, CollegeRivalry13_postIDs, 2151, 403, "September"],
         ["Saturday, September 28, 2013", "Homecoming Dance", 15400, Homecoming_postIDs, 2636, 346, "Fall"],
         ["Saturday, November 16, 2013", "My Fall Derby Style", 12222, FallDerbyStyle_postIDs, 2097, 309, "Fall"],
         ["Saturday, April 26, 2014", "Opening Night 2014", 24431, OpeningNight14_postIDs, 2547, 443, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, June 14, 2014", "The White Party 2014", 21671, WhiteParty14_postIDs, 1561, 231, "Spring"],
         ["Friday, June 27, 2014", "Rockin' in the USA", 18193, RockinUSA_postIDs, 342, 64, "Spring"],
         ["Friday, September 5, 2014", "College Rivalry Night 2014", 11058, CollegeRivalry14_postIDs, 1187, 243, "September"],
         ["Friday, September 19, 2014", "Oktoberfest", 14212, Oktoberfest_postIDs, 2467, 575, "September"],
         ["Saturday, June 13, 2015", "The White Party 2015", 28968, WhiteParty15_postIDs, 4631, 538, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, June 27, 2015", "Boots, Brew & BBQ 2015", 24192, BBQ15_postIDs, 811, 105, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, September 19, 2015", "Summer Sunset", 14786, SummerSunset_postIDs, 2435, 376, "September"],
         ["Saturday, June 18, 2016", "The White Party 2016", 19034, WhiteParty16_postIDs, 273, 40, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, July 2, 2016", "My Country Tis of Thee", 19621, MCTOT_postIDs, 226, 48, "Spring"],
         ["Saturday, September 24, 2016", "Bourbon, Bets & Bowties", 16768, BourbonBetsBowties_postIDs, 2470, 393, "September"]]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(FBDataSet)
df.columns = ["Date", "Theme", "Attendance", "PostIDs", "Likes", "Shares", "Meet"]
```

I have created variables by pulling columns from that dataframe:

```
All_Likes = df["Likes"]
All_Attendance = df["Attendance"]
All_Shares = df["Shares"]
All_Themes = df["Theme"]
```

I made a list of the individual samples in the "Themes" column:

```
All_Themeslist=[]
for x in All_Themes:
    All_Themeslist.append(x)
```

To prepare for my plt.bar chart, I set the correct number of xpositions:

```
xpositions = np.arrange(18)
```

I attempted to generate my bar chart with the following code:

```
plt.bar(xpositions, All_Likes)
plt.xticks(xpositions, All_Themeslist, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-521-b7ee361aed7a> in <module>()
     1 plt.bar(xpositions, All_Likes)
     ----> 2 plt.xticks(xpositions, All_Themeslist, rotation=90)
     3 plt.show()

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

So it seems that my code is not able to call the individual Theme names from my list "All_Themeslist"  It is reading it as a tuple instead.

The output I want is for the # of Likes to appear as bars, with each bar being labeled on the X axis with the Theme from the list "All_Themeslist."

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  Import code to follow:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

I also played around with trying to convert the tuple into a string:

```
Names = []
for x in All_Themeslist:
    Names.append
Names = str(Names)
```

I then substituted the new str variable "Names" for "All_Themeslist" in the original code.  Same results.

Comment: Could you share ([edit]) the whole traceback and create a [mcve]?

Comment: I added some more of my code that I think meets those requirements.  You should now be able to see the entire original dataframe (df) with the actual data I am using.

Comment: Are you able to plot the bar graph by omitting that erroneous line?

Comment: @NickilMaveli  Yes.  It works without that line.  The bar graph prints with just the numbers 0-17 on the xticks.

Comment: What do you get when you do `locs, labels = plt.xticks()`? Does it still throw an error? Are you able to print `locs` and `labels` separately?

Comment: @NickilMaveli I don't think I understand your question.  Bear in mind, I'm brand new to this.  I have the equivalent of a Berlitz intro tape on how to order in French....

Comment: Oddly enough, yes.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you've provided us the entire code and not missed any intermediate step in between? Everything including the import statements? Please double check once. BTW, it works fine for me in Python `3.5` / Matplotlib `1.5.3`

Comment: I am also in Python 3.5/Matplotlib 1.5.3.  I added the import code I have used to the bottom of my question above, along with a workaround I attempted (turning tuple into a string).

Comment: I noticed a typo in this line:  xpositions = np.arrange(18)  I thought maybe it was reading xpositions as a tuple.  Even after correcting the typo, I still get the same error.  Is that line of code causing problems?

Comment: Also, why have you imported the `pyplot` module twice(one absolute and the other relative)? Just remove that line `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. That would be causing the `plt` statements to fail. Now, run the code again. Does it work then?

Comment: If I just delete and re-run the cells with from matplotlib import pyplot as plt will that do it?  Or do I need to specifically "unimport" matplotlib

Comment: Delete just `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and re-run.

Comment: Ok--I did that and am still getting the same error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/hzttcRrA - Sample of your data (working code)

Comment: However, I am now getting the chart printout at the bottom of the out cell (after the error).  It still does not have the Themes as the xticks.

Comment: I just ran the sampel you posted in pastebin, and I got the same error.  Again, it printed out a bar chart but WITHOUT the Themes added as labels on the xticks.  Are you saying that works for you?

Comment: Yep, it does. Maybe you could post an [issue on their Github page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues). The maintainers would be able to help you further.

Comment: Ok---I just ran the samplebin code in a new Python root....and it WORKED!!!!  Thank you!!!!  Can you explain why this would be the case, though?  Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @NickilMaveli  How can I thank you?  Do you want to post a summary of your comments as an answer so that I can upvote it and accept it for the community to see?

Comment: Nice to see that it worked! I have no clue how it did. You may be a better person to figure out how it did work indeed. Maybe restarting the kernel did the trick, or removing those double import statements? Once you've known the exact reason, you can write that as an answer and accept it too :-)